# Lucee structure key access issue

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to convert one app from CF to lucee and facing issues into accessing structure. I have below code which is working fine in CF.

```
m = {};
m.arrHtml = [];

m.col           = [];
m.dataIdx       = [];
m.align         = [];
m.doHeader      = true;

arrayAppend(m.col,'abc');
arrayAppend(m.dataIdx,'xyz');
```

when I am trying to access the same in Lucee. I am getting error  - key [col] doesn't exist.

Any help/guidance will be really helpful.

I have trying accessing with . notation as well as m['col'] but it didn't work.

Comment: Your code works fine on Lucee as far as I can tell: https://trycf.com/gist/a4d025409e9e1ed71be750fa025b5918/lucee5?theme=monokai. Can you come up with a runnable (on trycf.com) example of what you are seeing?

Comment: Agreed.  I just tested it in a simple .cfm file and it worked as expected.  (Though these days, with so much of my work going into Javascript, I always favor m["col"] vs. m.col just to ensure casing.)